# Bulk editing products doesn't work correctly

Tags: magento2, product, bulk-products-update

I'm having an issue on my store. I've got around 2000 items in my product list. I used the magento data migration tools to convert 1.9 to 2.3 successfully. All the products, and the images are showing in the product list.

Currently non of them are showing on the actual store. To have them show I have to do the following to each item in order for it to show on the store:

1. Set stock to unmanaged (so there's no need to add quantity, we have unlimited stock)
2. Set **waiting for delivery qty** to no (for some reason its set to yes on all products)
3. Set **out of stock period** to no (again, for some reason it's set to yes on all)
4. Set **manual supply need qty** to no (same as above)

If I bulk edit 4 items for example, and hit save, I get the message appear:

```
Task "Update attributes for 4 selected products": 1 item(s) have been successfully updated.
```

and

```
Message is added to queue
```

If I clear cache and check the store they don't appear.

But, if I then edit each product individually and hit the save button without making any changes the product then appears on the store.

Any idea why I have to go into each product individually just to press save?

Comment: when u edit single product it will save directly. but when u edit bulk product and save then it will add in queue. so after sometime when your cron run it will update. or you can run cron manually

Comment: are you able to solve this?